# Can I replace Command Line Options

Tags: install4j

I have this option of other installer
install.exe -D$FORCE_UPDATE$=true -l en

This is the option of other installer.

This means below. 
If $FORCE_UPDATE$ key is "true" value, install language is English without language Selection dialog.

I want to use this option without modification.
I already knew that How to skip language Selection dialog like this.
install.exe -Dinstall4j.language=en
install.exe -Vsys.languageId=en

But, I would like to use old option 
I can't modify this option since I have already released old version.

Can you give me  the method about this issue??
Can I use this option programattically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the installer, install4j translates

```
-D$FORCE_UPDATE$=true
```

to a system property (like the command line syntax for VM parameters for the java executable), so you can query

```
Boolean.getBoolean("$FORCE_UPDATE$")
```

in code snippets in install4j.